# Third cohomology group of abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

What is the third cohomology group $H^3(C_n,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ of the cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$?

How can I calculate the third cohomology group of finite abelian group $A$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$? Is there any formula like Knuth formula for homology?

Comment: Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Universal coeffcient theorem for cohomology which states that
$$0\to\text{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(H_{n-1}(X),M)\to H^n(X,M)\to\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(H_n(X),M)\to 0$$
is exact, with $M$ being an abelian group, the coefficients, and $X$ being our group or space in question.

Let's remember that We have for $C_n\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$ and that $H_n(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\mathbb{Z}_n$ for even $n$, and $0$ otherwise, except when $n=0$ at which it is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Then using [this](http://math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/torext.pdf) handy guide we get that 
$$\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(H_n(\mathbb{Z}_m),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_m)\cong\mathbb{Z}_m$$
using [this](https://books.google.se/books?id=2fzlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=hom%20group%20Q/Z&source=bl&ots=6jx8EVAc-3&sig=BmpkHzbtan7sGeVR3kt_sOSLB3I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIvNbOwL3JAhUki3IKHeR6A7kQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=hom%20group%20Q%2FZ&f=false) for help, this is when $n$ is even.

For ext we have that $\text{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=0$

I think you can take it from here with it being a split sequence.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped.

Comment: Malam Sorry, I could not do it. I was ill these days.

Comment: No worries man! It happens to us all, I am just glad it helped. I'll be honest it was fresh in my memory after taking the course XP